# Android Studio Changes in source file does not update

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio Version 1.5. I have my project build on Gradle. Sometimes when I make changes in source files or XML layouts when I run the project the changes are not reflected in the app. I have to Sync gradle file again and then when I run the project it says If i want to uninstall the app. Then I can see the updated changes. Can you help me please what I am missing over here. I have

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
```

Or I have to do Clean before and then the changes are reflected.

Comment: yes it is advisable to clean the project

Comment: thanks Yes but every time should i clean the project?  @AndroidMechanic

Comment: if the changes you make require it yes. Generally layout and resource changes demand it.

Comment: @AndroidMechanic ok thanks for the help but still its kind of tedious in that case to clean first and then run the project.